# .Net Framework - Can't Debug Owin API Controllers

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, owin

I have a Web API in .NET Framework 4.8 using Owin. I have the following startup code:

```
        _callHttpServer = WebApp.Start(
            callServerOwinStartOptions,
            (appBuilder) =>
            {
                var httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
                httpConfig.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
                httpConfig.EnsureInitialized();
                httpConfig.ConfigureSwagger();
                appBuilder.UseWebApi(httpConfig);
            }
        );
```

However, when I set a breakpoint in one of my `ApiController` classes, it is never hit, even when I know the route is running. Furthermore, I can't see the outputs of any `Console.WriteLine()` statements I add to the controller.

What's the catch? How do I make this work?